# Can I use a modified variable without creating a new one in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to use a modified version of a variable (without changing the original one) only once, so I don't want to save it in a new variable.

For example:

```
a = [1 -2 3];
copy = a;
copy(a < 0) = 0;
b = [4 5 6] .* copy;
```

Can I simplify that to something like the following?

```
a = [1 -2 3];
b = [4 5 6] .* a(<0 = 0);
```

**Edit**:

The example above is just an example. The general problem is how to get the `copy` produced by the code below, without creating it.

```
% `a` is a vector
% `cond` is a logical vector such as `size(a) == size(cond)`
% `num` is a number
copy = a;
copy(cond) = num;
```

Comment: There is *almost always* a different way to express a problem without using a temporary variable. In some cases you sacrifice readability, and in other cases you improve readability.  In cases where performance is not an issue, I say go for the most readable solution. One possibility is `b = [4 5 6].*a.*(a>=0)`

Comment: @nispio Thanks, I hadn't thought about multiplying a vector by its logical. Your idea has helped me to find a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19695519/1529630) of the general problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general problem

```
% `a` is a vector
% `cond` is a logical vector such as `size(a) == size(cond)`
% `num` is a number
copy = a;
copy(cond) = num;
```

Instead of creating `copy`, one of the following can be used:

- `a + (-a+num) .* cond`
- `a .* ~cond + num * cond`

**Warning**: doesn't work if `num` is one of the following:  `nan`, `inf`, `-inf` (and maybe more)

**Performance**

It seems that `a + (-a+num) .* cond` is faster:

```
a = rand(1, 10000);  cond = a < 0.5;  num = 10;

tic; for i=1:100000 a + (-a+num) .* cond; end; toc;
% Elapsed time is 14.764796 seconds.

tic; for i=1:100000 a .* ~cond + num * cond; end; toc;
% Elapsed time is 29.842845 seconds.
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you can do

```
b = [4 5 6] .* max(0, a)
```

But why do you ask this? Do you want to save memory when you do something similar with big  matrices? Or do you want to write more compact code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the syntax you are looking for exists in Matlab.

Obviously, your real use case might be more complicated than this, but I would change your code to this to remove the extraneous `copy` variable:

```
a = [1 -2 3];
b = [4 5 6] .* a;
b(a < 0) = 0;
```

See: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25235

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an [`anonymous function`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) which applies the desired modification to your variable:

```
f = @(x) max(x,0); % this will apply the desired operation to a
a = [1 -2 3];
b = [4 5 6] .* f(a);
```

The modification required on `a` needs to be simple enough, so that it can be defined using an anonymous function. Specifically, according to the above link,

> Anonymous functions can contain only a single executable statement.

Comment: I have always found it a bit strange to call it an anonymous function once you give it a name...

Comment: @nispio I tend to agree. But according to Mathworks, `f` is the name of the function handle, not of the function itself. http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Comment: And yet you can invoke the function using `f(args)`.  If it looks like a function,  and quacks like a function...  On the other hand, it might confuse the issue even more to say that when `f = @(args) ...` it is an anonymous function when passed as an argument to another function, but a "named" function when invoked through `f(args)`.